# Pulling JSON object from JSON array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, highcharts

I have been surfing SO for quite some time to find an answer to my question, and I have to admit that I am stumped. I think I must be missing something very simple here but right now I can't see the wood for the trees.

I am trying to load a highchart via JSON, and the JSON is created by a PHP array (the reason for this is that I am retrieving the data from MySQL.) The series are loading fine, however I cannot extract the title for the chart. My understanding is that the code for that needs to be something like json.title.text ... however this does not work and crashes the script. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**The PHP array is as follows (I have put dummy variable to simplify...):**

```
    $arr = 
array (
    array (
        'title' => array (
            'text' => 'idiot'
        ),
        'data' => array (
            '2012-12-16; 0',
            '2012-12-16; 23'
        )
    ),
    array (
        'name' => 'Sacred cows',
        'data' => array (
            98.9914,
            99.5429
        )
    ),

);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

**The javascript that generates the charts is as follows:**

```
  function marketwidget(id){

var formData = "name="+ id + "&age=31";

$.ajax({
    url : "marketwidget.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
            var json = JSON.parse(data)

    var len = json.length
    i = 0;

    var options = {
   title: {
        text: []
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: []
        },
        series: []
    }

        options.title.text = json.title.text

    for (i; i < len; i++) {
        if (i === 0) {
            var dat = json[i].data,
                lenJ = dat.length,
                j = 0,
                tmp;

            for (j; j < lenJ; j++) {
                tmp = dat[j].split(';');
                options.xAxis.categories.push(tmp[0]);
            }
        } else {
                options.series.push(json[i]);
        }
    }



    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', options);

        },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
    }
});

}
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). Why don't you use jQuery's functionality to create a query string? Now you'll have to use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to properly encode query string parameters. And you can also use `'json'` as last parameter of `$.post`, so you don't have to manually use `JSON.parse`, which might not be available.

Comment: Did you try `console.log` on the response data? It’s usually very easy to fond the structure from there.

Comment: your json structure is not built in a way that can be easily iterated over. The meta data should be separated from the results. That or you don't need to iterate over it at all.

Comment: David, thanks for your answer. Not sure what console.log does, but the "output" ajax response data is as follows: [{"title":{"text":"idiot"},"data":["2012-12-16; 0","2012-12-16; 23"]},{"name":"Sacred cows","data":[98.9914,99.5429]}]

Comment: `json.title.text` is wrong. Given the array of objects you just posted, how do you think you should access the `title` property of the **first** object in the **array**?

Comment: Kevin -I am not sure but I think you must be right. I keep on getting undefined errors. How would I access the first object in the array?

Comment: `thearray[0]` would get the first item in the array. Your for loop doesn't make sense given the structure of your json.

Comment: Kevin B you rock. How do I vote for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are reading the parsed json is incorrect.  I was able to access the title when I tried `json[i].title.text`.

The array index is missing in the line : `options.title.text = json.title.text`. You can try `options.title.text = json[0].title.text` instead.

```
<script>
  var json = JSON.parse('[{"title":{"text":"idiot"},"data":["2012-12-16; 0","2012$


  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
     document.write(json[i].title.text); 
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you to Kevin B and Rayhan for their answers to this question